# Today extension enable internet connection iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, http, today-extension

I'm testing an today extension and I'm trying to download a google's home page (for testing) and I have this code in the today extension's class:

```
- (void)widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NCUpdateResult))completionHandler {
    // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.

    // If an error is encountered, use NCUpdateResultFailed
    // If there's no update required, use NCUpdateResultNoData
    // If there's an update, use NCUpdateResultNewData
    NSURL *urltest = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.it"];
    NSData *testData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urltest];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:testData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    completionHandler(NCUpdateResultNewData);

}
```

but I have this problem:

if the link is: https://www.google.it everything work (testData is not nil), while if the link is http://www.google.it testData is nil (it's like to it not be able to connect).

In the .plist of the application I set the 'NSAllowsArbitraryLoads' to YES.

N.B if I use this code in the main application (not in the extension) everything work both https and http

Can you help me please?

Comment: Did you put the ATS exception in the extension's plist?

Comment: no, how do I do it?

Comment: where is the extension's plist?

Answer (score 0):

Add `App Transport Security` to `Info Plist`.

[image]